# Backup Raspberry Partition Layout?

Tags: backup

I've noticed that when doing backups of Linux Machines there tend to be two parts: File Backups and partition layout backups.

File Backups backup the non-os type files that are unique to you, and configuration files.

Software packages are loaded by your distro / repository.

However, no disastery recovery solution is complete without a partition layout recovery backup and restore.  In other Linux distros this comes in the form of REAR which outputs a bootable ISO or PXE image from which to recover the partion layout to another drive before restoring your file backups.

OpenWRT also appears to have a process for doing this (
https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.backup)  How does one make a partion backup for a Raspberry PI SD card?

Answer (score 1):

If you use raspbian you can use almost any tool that is available for debian based Linux distribions.

Because I prefer simple solutions, I use command line tools `dd` which can give you single partition image or entire disk image as `.img` file, which in turn can be mounted on any linux distribution AFAIK.

```
# backup entire disk to *img
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/path/to/image.img bs=1M

# backup just first partition '/boot'
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p1 of=/path/to/image.img bs=1M

# backup just second partition '/'
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p2 of=/path/to/image.img bs=1M

# backup entire disk and also compress on the fly
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M | bzip2 -c > /path/to/image.img.bz2
```

The `dd` command can be also used for writing `.img` to another sdcard and it would be bootable if you backup entire disk.

It is strong suggested to read `man dd` before play with this tool, because one can mess a bit, if use it wrong.